# ReactJS and jQuery Mobile Tables - how to optimally re-render table after update store

Tags: reactjs, jquery-mobile-table

I re-render jqmobile table this way and all work:

```
var List = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount:function(){
    $(".list-box-app-list").table();
  },

  componentDidUpdate:function(){
    $(".list-box-app-list").table();
  },

  render: function() {
    var allListItems = this.props.allListItems;
    var listItems = [];

    for (var key in allListItems) {
      listItems.push(<ListItem key={key} list_item={allListItems[key]} />); 
    }

    return (
      <table  data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" className="ui-responsive list-box-app-list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-priority="2">Id</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th data-priority="1">Text</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {listItems}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

});
```

Example is here: https://eugen35@bitbucket.org/eugen35/flux-todomvc.git

branch: listAndJQMobile

```
npm install
npm run watch // create bundle.js
npm start // run server.js
```

**Is there way to do this more optimally?**

Cause my example i think work so:
1) (re)render JSX in DOM, 2) INITIALIZE JQMobile-table with .table();
Earler I have supposed, that reactDOM only renew some new rows in my table and i do not have to reinitialize JQM-table. But this not work. Probably reactjs after each update rerender in DOM whole table. And from that i need to reinitialize it as JQM table.

*What do i do wrong?*

Comment: I have noticed, that JQM tables works incorrect in my case:

Comment: After i have dynamicaly added some row, - for those rows component does not work, - they were not be hidden, when i change window size. To all work i have changed code above for this:

Comment: ' componentDidMount:function(){
    $(".list-box-app-list").table().table("refresh");
  },

  componentDidUpdate:function(){
    $(".list-box-app-list").table().table("refresh");
  },'

Comment: **But question about optimality of my code is still on the agenda!**